# Detect when iframe is cross-domain, then bust out of it

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, cross-domain

I have a page with a large iframe that contains a majority of the content. The user interacts with the website by clicking around within the iframe. The functionality I'm trying to build is: When a user navigates away from my site, I do them a favor and bust out of the iframe.

The iframe has an onload event which is fired every time a new page is loaded, cross-domain or not.

```
<iframe id="testframe" src="http://mysite.com" onload="testframe_loaded()"></iframe>
```

Each time the event is fired, I'm looking for some way to:

**A**) Detect when the user navigates to a different domain

**B**) Bust out of the iframe.

I suspect that B isn't possible, since browsers don't give access to

```
document.getElementById("testframe").contentDocument.location.href
```

when the iframe is cross-domain. I'm also not sure whether or not A is possible.

If anybody has ideas as to how to accomplish this, or is positive that it can't be done, I'd appreciate the advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do A, since if you get a security error (which you can catch), that's means they're cross-domain :)  Then you can resize the iframe to be the whole page.  But I think you're right you can't actually bust out, without explicit cooperation from the other domain.

EDIT: You're right you don't need to poll.  Here's the basic code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cross-domain frame test</title>
<!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365822/detect-when-iframe-is-cross-domain-then-bust-out-of-it/2365853#2365853 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForCross()
{
  var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  try
  {
    var loc = iframe.contentDocument.location.href;
  } catch(e)
  {
    iframe.setAttribute("style", "border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name="myFrame" id="myFrame" src="child.html" style="height: 50%; width: 50%;" onload="checkForCross()"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll test the try/catch approach.. I always forget that JavaScript supports that :) Polling isn't necessary though, since I can just test it each time the iframe's onload event is fired.

Comment: This definitely works and demonstrates that A is possible. Unfortunately B still seems impossible -- expanding the iframe works, but it's still wonky because the url in the browser's location bar won't match the site being displayed.

I'll try to play around a bit with solutions involving modifying the the links that the other answers suggest, e.g. attaching a click handler to every link that checks if the href attribute is cross-domain.

Comment: Emmett, the click handler works, but only for /your/ links, not links within the iframe.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the try/catch block doesn't prevent an error from appearing in Chrome or Safari's error console. Anyone know how to do A in those browsers?

Comment: the error isn't catch-able (at least on chrome).  Execution continues but access to any cross-domain variable is returned as undefined.  See my answer below for a code example.

Answer (score 2):

set the 'target' attribute on external links to '_top'.

Comment: Which you can do when not cross domain by walking the BOM.

Answer (score 1):

This works for chrome at least (not tester on other browsers)

```
   if(parent.location.host != undefined){ 
       alert("hello world!");
    }else{
       throw "cannot access parent!";
    }
```

It will still throw the `"unsafe javascript attempt"` warning, but this doesn't stop code execution.  Instead the variable is returned as undefined.