# Pull parent page url to chrome extension in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

I have some JavaScript code that returns the current visited page's url. This code runs as a `href` link. I would like to make it do the same when I open it using a Chrome extension that opens a page in an iframe (can be different domain). The iframe opens fine but the url does not populate. I have tried `window.parent.location` types to no avail.

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://www.example.com/..?s=%20'
    +encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'%20'
    +encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'%20'
    +encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection())))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637579/1587329 might help you